# Getting date difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please help me in getting date difference between two dates in SQL server.
Below query giving error

```
 DATEDIFF(DD,(convert(date,[Fdate])),(convert(date,[Ldate])))[DDiff]
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Why are you storing dates in `varchar` columns?

Comment: Can't help you without knowing the error message

Answer (score 3):

Since you are on SQL Server 2012, use `try_convert()`:

```
select datediff(day,try_convert(date,[fdate]),try_convert(date,[ldate])) as ddiff
```

---

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

---

The main issue may be that you are storing dates as a character data type. If so, that can cause additional issues depending on what format the date is stored in.

You may need to specify a [style with **`try_convert()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), or [**`set dateformat`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) to `MDY` or `DMY`, or use a specific culture with [**`try_parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx).